# PHP Array - Select object based on set parameters

Tags: php, arrays, icloud

I am using a php script to track my iPhones positions for a project. The script I'm using can be found here on [github](https://github.com/tylerhall/sosumi). The issue I'm facing however is that it's tracking to devices. My laptop AND my iPhone. I want it to track just the iPhone however I want the ability to easily switch between the two devices if need be; in other words I want priority to be given to track the iPhone then the laptop. So I'm thinking of using the "`deviceClass`" to determine what device to select but I have no idea how to add it into the file: [class.sosumi.php](https://github.com/tylerhall/sosumi/blob/master/PHP/class.sosumi.php) Here's the array output here:

```
    Sosumi Object
(
    [devices] => Array
        (
            [0] => SosumiDevice Object
                (
                    [isLocating] => 1
                    [locationTimestamp] => **
                    [locationType] => Wifi
                    [horizontalAccuracy] => 65
                    [locationFinished] => 1
                    [longitude] => **
                    [latitude] => **
                    [deviceModel] => MacBookPro7_1
                    [deviceStatus] => 200
                    [id] => **
                    [name] => **
                    [deviceClass] => MacBookPro
                    [chargingStatus] => 
                    [batteryLevel] => 0
                )

            [1] => SosumiDevice Object
                (
                    [isLocating] => 1
                    [locationTimestamp] => **
                    [locationType] => Wifi
                    [horizontalAccuracy] => 65
                    [locationFinished] => 1
                    [longitude] => **
                    [latitude] => **
                    [deviceModel] => FourthGen
                    [deviceStatus] => 203
                    [id] => **
                    [name] => **
                    [deviceClass] => iPhone
                    [chargingStatus] => NotCharging
                    [batteryLevel] => 0.5866984
                )

        )

   )
```

Any help with figuring out how to get this working would be appreciated. It seems easy but for some reason I can't get it working.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I've got your question clearly, but you need either:

#### [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Which will allow you filter your array like this:

```
// Reference is implicit (I've added & for you to see it)!!!
// Be careful not to change your data
functon filterCallback( SosumiDevice &$obj){ 
    return $obj->deviceClass == 'MacBookPro';
}
```

#### [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Sort array that first are MacBooks

```
function usortCallback( SosumiDevice $a, SosumiDevice $b){
    static $order = array(
         'MacBookPro' => 1,
         'FourthGen' => 2,
         ...
    );

    $oA = isset( $order[ $a->deviceClass]) ? $order[ $a->deviceClass] : -100;
    $oB = isset( $order[ $b->deviceClass]) ? $order[ $b->deviceClass] : -100;

    // Maybe reverse order of operands will be necessary
    return $oA - $oB;
}
```

This adds values classes like this:

- `MacBookPro => 1`
- `FourGen => 2`

Therefore when you add params like: `MacBookPro, FourthGen`

It's evaluated as: `1 - 2`, which returns `-1` => `MacBookPro` should be before `FourthGen`

#### `foreach` loop

Split devices to groups based on device type:

```
$groups = array();
foreach( $this->devices as $device){
    if( !isset( $groups[ $device->deviceType])){
        $groups[ $device->deviceType] = array( $device);
        continue;
    }
    $groups[ $device->deviceType] = $device;
}
```

You can achieve the same with array filter, this would be more effective if you need to get all groups, `array_filter` when you need just one gruop.